# AMQP Multitasking

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp, eventmachine

I have an interesting situation that I need to fulfill.  I need to have an EventMachine loop that sits and waits for messages in an AMQP queue but then interrupts that loop in order to send out a message to a separate AMQP queue on a regular interval.  I'm new to EventMachine and this is what I have so far, except the EventMachine loop doesn't send the necessary message.

Right now I've made two procs:

```
    listen_loop = Proc.new {
        AMQP.start(connection_config) do |connection|
            AMQP::Channel.new(connection) do |channel|
                channel.queue("queue1", :exclusive => false, :durable => true) do |requests_queue|
                    requests_queue.once_declared do
                        consumer = AMQP::Consumer.new(channel, requests_queue).consume
                        consumer.on_delivery do |metadata, payload|
                            puts "[requests] Got a request #{metadata.message_id}. Sending a reply to #{metadata.reply_to}..."
                            response = "responding"
                            channel.default_exchange.publish(response,
                                :routing_key    => metadata.reply_to,
                                :correlation_id => metadata.message_id,
                                :mandatory      => true)
                            metadata.ack
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        Signal.trap("INT")  { AMQP.stop { EM.stop } }
        Signal.trap("TERM") { AMQP.stop { EM.stop } }
    }

    send_message = Proc.new {
        AMQP.start(connection_config) do |connection|
            channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
            queue   = channel.queue('queue2')

            channel.default_exchange.publish("hello world", :routing_key => queue.name)
            EM.add_timer(0.5) do
                connection.close do
                    EM.stop{ exit }
                end
            end
        end
    }
```

And then I have my EventMachine Loop:

```
    EM.run do 
        EM.add_periodic_timer(5) { send_message.call }
        listen_loop.call
    end
```

I am able to receive messages in the listen loop but I am unable to send off any of the messages on the regular interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what I was doing wrong.  The message loop wasn't able to open up a new connection to the RabbitMQ server because it was already connected.  Consolidated everything into a single EventMachine loop and reused the connection and it works.

For those curious it looks like this:

```
EM.run do

    AMQP.start(connection_config) do |connection|
        channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)

        EM.add_periodic_timer(5) { channel.default_exchange.publish("foo", :routing_key => 'queue2') }

        queue = channel.queue("queue1", :exclusive => false, :durable => true)
        channel.prefetch(1)
        queue.subscribe(:ack => true) do |metadata, payload|
            puts "[requests] Got a request #{metadata.message_id}. Sending a reply to #{metadata.reply_to}..."
            response = "bar"
            channel.default_exchange.publish(response,
                :routing_key    => metadata.reply_to,
                :correlation_id => metadata.message_id,
                :mandatory      => true)
            metadata.ack
        end
    end
    Signal.trap("INT")  { AMQP.stop { EM.stop } }
    Signal.trap("TERM") { AMQP.stop { EM.stop } }

end
```